# Maven surefire forkMode pertest deprecated. What is the new settings?

Tags: java, maven, automated-tests, maven-surefire-plugin, surefire

As of Surefire 2.14 the `forkMode` configuration setting has been deprecated. They even helpfully provide a mapping from some of the old settings to new settings here (http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html).

The problem is we use `<forkMode>pertest</forkMode>` which does not have a mapping on that page, and my google-fu is failing to find the appropriate updated configuration for it.

What is the appropriate `forkCount`, `reuseForks`, `parallel` and/or other configuration to replace the deprecated `forkMode=pertest` setting?

Comment: Pretty sure this is the same as `parallel=classesAndMethods`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That isn't mentioned in the documentation, but `<forkMode>pertest</forkMode>` is the same as always forking. This is [the check in the code](https://github.com/apache/maven-surefire/blob/surefire-2.19.1/maven-surefire-common/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/surefire/booterclient/ForkConfiguration.java#L108-L111):

> ```
> if ( "pertest".equalsIgnoreCase( forkMode ) )
> {
>     return FORK_ALWAYS;
> }
> ```

This synonym was made during resolution of the JIRA issue [SUREFIRE-96](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-96), where, [quoting Brett Porter](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-96?focusedCommentId=14453339&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-14453339):

> pertest and perTest still work, but I've changed it to "always" which seems consistent with "once", and also changed "none" to "never".

As such, you should migrate your current configuration of `<forkMode>pertest</forkMode>` to `forkCount=1` and `reuseForks=false`, like mentioned in [Migrating the Deprecated forkMode Parameter to forkCount and reuseForks](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html#Migrating_the_Deprecated_forkMode_Parameter_to_forkCount_and_reuseForks).

Comment: The mapping table you linked is unfortunately no longer on the page, but can still be accessed via https://web.archive.org/web/20161029173525/http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html#Migrating_the_Deprecated_forkMode_Parameter_to_forkCount_and_reuseForks

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace

```
<forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
```

with

```
<forkCount>1</forkCount>
<reuseForks>false</reuseForks>
```